# Convert oracle to JPA createQuery

Tags: oracle, jpa

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  CUSTOMER_MASTER t0, 
  (SELECT t1.COMMNUMBER, t1.COMMTYPE FROM FOLLOWUP_GUIDES t1 WHERE (t1.STAGE_ID = '5')) t2
WHERE (t0.FOLL_UP_NUM = t2.COMMNUMBER 
and T0.FOLL_UP_TYPE=t2.COMMTYPE AND (t0.COMPANY_ID = 'C001'))
```

In the above oracle query i have to got the follupnum and folluptype in the combination commnumber and commtype. But is it possible to write this query in JPA?

Answer (score 1):

JPA fully supports SQL queries.  You can use createNativeQuery(sql) or @NamedNativeQuery.

You could probably also reword your query in terms of JPQL.

If you are using EclipseLink, it does support sub-selects in the FROM clause in JPQL,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause

Answer (score 1):

JPA fully supports SQL queries. You can use createNativeQuery(sql) or @NamedNativeQuery

once click this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Foreign Keys in place between CUSTOMER_MASTER and FOLLOWUP_GUIDES

i.e. Assuming

```
CUSTOMER_MASTER.FOLL_UP_NUM    is FK to   FOLLOWUP_GUIDES.COMMNUMBER 
CUSTOMER_MASTER.FOLL_UP_TYPE   is FK to   FOLLOWUP_GUIDES.COMMTYPE
```

Then your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  CUSTOMER_MASTER t0, 
  (SELECT t1.COMMNUMBER, t1.COMMTYPE FROM FOLLOWUP_GUIDES t1 
   WHERE (t1.STAGE_ID = '5')) t2
WHERE (t0.FOLL_UP_NUM = t2.COMMNUMBER 
and T0.FOLL_UP_TYPE=t2.COMMTYPE AND (t0.COMPANY_ID = 'C001'))
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER t0 JOIN FOLLOWUP_GUIDES t1
WHERE t0.COMPANY_ID = 'C001'
AND   t1.STAGE_ID = '5'
```

This can be done in JPA quite easily and looks very similar to this SQL (only using object names and field names instead of table names and attribute names).

JPA JPQL query will look something like this:

```
SELECT t0
FROM CustomerMaster t0 JOIN FollowupGuides t1
WHERE t0.companyId = "C001"
AND   t1.stageId = "5"
```

Can also do with JPA subquery:

```
SELECT t0
FROM CustomerMaster t0 
WHERE t0.companyId = "C001"
AND   EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM FollowupGuides t1
              WHERE t1.commnumber = t0.follUpNum
              AND   t1.commtype = t0.FollUpType
              AND   t1.stageId = "5")
```

=B)